# Marketing Cloud IP Warming - is it critical that we send up to the weekly limits by domain?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

For IP warming, is it critical that we send up to the weekly limits by domain?  For example, see screenshot below.  Notice each day as the max limit.  What if the customer only has a grand total 40,000 Yahoo email subscribers?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Recently had a similar implementation (surprisingly even similar amount of Contacts) and based on my discussions with Salesforce Success Manager and Salesforce Deliverability Team, you do not need to do an IP warm-up at all.

There are a couple of points to know here though.
If there was a SAP configured with shared IP, then you're clear. Nothing to do or worry about.

However if you got a private IP (which is standard) then you should avoid creating surprise spikes during Email sendouts.

What it means is if the daily rate is around 400-900 Emails for an example, then you should not do a send to 25000 subscribers without proper planning.

Request Salesforce Service Team to enable [Send Throttling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5) on the MC account and during large volume sends simply set some hourly/daily throttling on how many will be processed at once.

Comment: Thanks @Atheri - so if the client has say 40k Yahoo subscribers, then should I be breaking down that 40k to agree with the 4 week IP warming plan?  In other words, 20k per day is the absolute limit, but is it acceptable to send to, say, 600 per day instead of 20k, so as long as there aren't any spikes?

Comment: 20k number was an example of a spike as it will all depend on how big the daily average numbers will be. If service providers see that your daily norm would be 3-5k then a 20k jump wouldn't cross to the 'red zone' to say. IP warm up plans are generally for senders with larger volumes and smaller clients tend to share an IP. To answer your question - yes, 600 a day wouldn't be raising any flags at first, but you will still need to pay attention to bounce rates, unsubcribes and open-rates. In case you do need to have a large send, simply spread it.