# Is IP warming critical for subscriber base in < 20K

Tags: marketing-cloud, ip

We have less than 20K subscribers in Marketing Cloud in a new implementation.

Do we need to complete IP warming? If yes, what numbers should we be completing sends in and for what period of time?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232078/marketing-cloud-ip-warming-is-it-critical-that-we-send-up-to-the-weekly-limits

Comment: Is it on a shared IP? with such a low subscriber count, having a private IP can actually be more harmful than helpful.  If you do have a private IP, you would still need to at the least do IP warming on the domain level - see @SamuelDare s link in his comment for more info on that.